# Can "tam" be correlated by itself with "ut"?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice

After reading the comments in [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/john-316-in-latin), I wanted to clarify whether a certain proposed usage of *tam* is appropriate. In it, *tam* was proposed as an emphatic alternative to *sic*, when correlated with *ut*, e.g.:

> Tam enim eam amabam ut omnia ei darem.
>
> <sup>For I loved her so much that I gave her everything.</sup>

(If this was not the proposed construction, please let me know!)

My question: **Can *tam* be correlated with *ut* in this way?** Seeing *tam* used "alone" with a verb strikes me as strange: I am used to seeing it used with an adjective or adverb ("tam bonus sum") and/or correlated with *quam*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dtam) (way down the page) rule this possibility out:

> III. As demonstr. adv. of intensity, correlative with ut, that, and its equivalents (qui, quin); so only with adjj. and advv. (not with verbs).

Other answers have shown uses of this with adjectives and adverbs, and it is easy (e.g. in the same L&S entry) to find examples of *tam* alone with verbs but without consecutive *ut.* However, it seems that what you are looking for (*tam* + verb + *ut*) is not attested. Of course, L&S might have overlooked some obscure passage, or some long-lost attestation might have been discovered in the last decades, but I’d bet against it.

As for Latin used in the Renaissance and later, it is very unlikely to find a counterexample there; the traditional teaching is/was that you don’t use *tam* with verbs alone, without adjectives or adverbs: “Plautus could, you cannot” would say my late teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ***tam* can be correlated with *ut***. Here are some examples:

> Plaut. *Rud.* 756-757: *ni erit **tam** sincerum, **ut** quivis dicat
>   ampullarius / optimum esse operi faciundo corium*
>
> Ter. *Hec.* 108-109: *numquam **tam** dices commode **ut** tergum meum
>   / tuam in fidem committam*
>
> Caes. *Gall.* 1,44,9: *non se **tam** barbarum neque tam imperitum
>   esse rerum **ut** non sciret ...*
>
> Cic. *Arch.* 17: *quis **tam** animo agresti fuit **ut** non
>   commoveretur?*
>
> Liv. 5,51,4: *tamen **tam** euidens numen hac tempestate rebus adfuit
>   Romanis **ut** omnem neglegentiam diuini cultus exemptam hominibus
>   putem*
>
> Sen. *nat.* 1,15,5: *caelum ardere uisum, cuius nonnumquam **tam**
>   sublimis ardor est **ut** inter sidera ipsa uideatur*
>
> Tac. *ann.* 4,11: *neque quisquam scriptor **tam** infensus extitit
>   **ut** Tiberio obiectaret*
>
> Iuv. 8,211: *quis **tam** / perditus **ut** dubitet Senecam praeferre
>   Neroni?*

Comment: I apologize because my question title was not clear: I am primarily curious about whether it can be correlated *alone*, I.e. without an adverb or adjective

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I realized the point of your question just after have posted the answer. However, tomorrow I will look if I could find some examples of the use you are looking for